# Bootstrap datepicker make one selectable date each 7 days

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to implement a feature on my calendars but i have no ideia on how to do it, what i want to achieve:

As soon i select a date in my first datepicker, i want the other datepicker to restrict the dates i can pick: make so that i only can pick the selected date on the first calendar plus 7 days, plus 14 days, etc, from 7 to 7 days i can pick that date and disable other dates.

```
$('#startdateajna').datepicker({
    startDate: date,
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    console.log('trigger');

    var oldDate = new Date(e.date);
    var newDate = new Date();
    newDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() + 7);

    $('#enddateajna').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#startdateajna').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',                        
    onSelect: function (selected) 
    {
        var date2 = $('#startdateajna').datepicker('getDate');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 7);
        $("#enddateajna").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
        $("#enddateajna").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date2);                          
    }
});
```

Comment: That does not do what i want

Comment: Could you explain the question clearly.. what you need to do in the second datepicker?? Is that you need to restrict till 7 days or 14 days??